# How to get a loop not to overwrite the results?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I feel dumb asking such a simple question, but I can't seem to find a way, although I'm sure there are plenty of ways. The easiest way to explain my problem might be to show an example, I've got some program I want applied.

```
FUN<- function(v1, v2, v3){
  n=length(v1)
  res <- vector()
  for (i in 1:n){
    if(v1[i]>v2[i]) (res[i] <- v3[i+2])
      else(res[i] <- v1[i+2])}
  return(res)}
```

The input is two vectors and a matrix, all being the same length

```
matrix <- matrix(runif(30),ncol=3) 
v2 <- runif(10)
v3 <- rnorm(10)
```

So that when I run the a for loop including the function I can do the program `i` times and each time the output goes to a different column in a matrix. I've tried something like and several similar "versions", but with no luck.

```
for (i in 1:3)(
r <- matrix()
r[re,i] <- re <- FUN(matrix[,i], v2, v3))
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your for loop in `FUN` accesses elements `n+1` and `n+2` of a vector with `n` elements -- is this a typo?

Comment: There is no `i`th column in the matrix `r` it is an empty matrix. Also, you need braces `{ ... }` after the `for ()` bit, as in `for () { .... }`, not parentheses.

Comment: Besides that, you are creating a new matrix every time inside your loop!

Comment: Ah yeah, the matrix inside the for-loop and the brackets are just typos when trying to create a reproducible example, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r <- matrix(ncol=3, nrow=10)
for (i in 1:3) {
  r[,i] <- FUN(matrix[,i], v2, v3)
}
```

Declare your matrix outside the loop, and just fill in one column per loop iteration.

(This assumes that `FUN` is correct; even if it is, there are better ways to do what it does. And other ways to do what you want other than a loop.)